# Prove that M(2,2) is not a subspace of given vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

The problem is:

> Determine, with proof, if the set is a subspace of the given vector space

$\{\begin{bmatrix}a_{1}&a_{2}\\a_{3}&a_{4}\end{bmatrix} | a_{1}a_{4} - a_{2}a_{3} = 0 , a_{1},  a_{2},a_{3},a_{4}\in\mathbb{R}\}$

How im trying to solve it:

It contains the null vector since $a_{1} = a_{2} = a_{3}= a_{4 } = 0 $  satisfies the condition.

Checking if it is closed under addition

$ \overrightarrow{a} =\begin{bmatrix}a_{1}&a_{2}\\a_{3}&a_{4}\end{bmatrix}$ , $ \overrightarrow{b}=\begin{bmatrix}b_{1}&b_{2}\\b_{3}&b_{4}\end{bmatrix}$

$ \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} =\begin{bmatrix}a_{1}+b_{1}&a_{2}+b_1{b}\\a_{3}+b_{3}&a_{4}+b_{4}\end{bmatrix}$

Condition : $a_{1}a_{4} - a_{2}a_{3} = 0$

$(a_{1}+b_{1})(a_{4}+b_{4}) - (a_{2}+b_{2})(a_{3}+b_{3}) = 0 $ $\Leftrightarrow$

$a_{1}a_{4} + a_{1}b_{4} + b_{1}a_{4} + b_{1}b_{4} - a_{2}a_{3} - a_{2}b_{3} - b_{2}a_{3} - b_{2}b_{3} = 0 $ $\Leftrightarrow$

$(a_{1}a_{4} - a_{2}a_{3}) + (a_{1}b_{4} - a_{2}b_{3}) + (b_{1}a_{4}- b_{2}a_{3})  + (b_{1}b_{4}  - b_{2}b_{3}) = (0)+(0)+(0)+(0) = 0 $

and closed under multiplication by:

$ t\overrightarrow{a} =t\begin{bmatrix}a_{1}&a_{2}\\a_{3}&a_{4}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}ta_{1}&ta_{2}\\ta_{3}&ta_{4}\end{bmatrix}, t \in \mathbb{R} $

Condition : $a_{1}a_{4} - a_{2}a_{3} = 0$

$ta_{1}ta_{4} -t a_{2}ta_{3} = 0 $ $\Leftrightarrow$

$t^2a_{1}a_{4} -t^2a_{2}a_{3} = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$

$t^2(a_{1}a_{4} -a_{2}a_{3}) = t^2(0) =  0$

According to the solutions, it is not a subspace. This can also shown by

$ \overrightarrow{a} =\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\6&4\end{bmatrix}$ , $ \overrightarrow{b}=\begin{bmatrix}-8&1\\-24&3\end{bmatrix}$

$ \overrightarrow{a} + \overrightarrow{b} =\begin{bmatrix}-5&3\\-18&7\end{bmatrix}$

$ (-5)*7 - 3*(-18) \neq 0$

So something is obviously wrong in my solution, but I can't figure out what.
My only guess is that source of error is:

$a_{1}a_{4} - a_{2}a_{3} = 0$

doesn't imply that

$a_{1}b_{4} - a_{2}b_{3} = 0$ <- I assumed this was the case when eliminating in the closed under addition part

Comment: You are correct: you only know conditions about the $a_i$ relating to themselves, or the $b_i$ relating to themselves. You know no information about mixing $a$'s and $b$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On closure under addition:

you are trying to show that: $ (a_1a_4−a_2a_3)+(a_1b_4−a_2b_3)+(b_1a_4−b_2a_3)+(b_1b_4−b_2b_3) = 0$

The first and last terms equal $0,$  but there is no indication that the middle terms do.  And as you show in your counter example, they usually don't.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to come up with counterexample when you think what $a_1a_4-a_2a_3=0$ means. Your subset is precisely those matrices of determinant $0$, which are non-invertible matrices. To show that this subset is not closed under addition, my first thought would be if I could find invertible matrix and write it as sum of non-invertible matrices. The simplest invertible matrix is identity matrix, and

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1& 0\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0& 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

is a counterexample you are looking for.